# Gmap API: Load transitLayer after initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using the Gmap API to display a Google Map with a [transitLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-transit). I am trying to improve the [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) of my website. One of the things that would help is if I could load the transitLayer AFTER the Google Map is initialized. I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cz6h6frn/6/) in which the Google Map is initialized with the transitLayer. Is it possible to add the transitLayer AFTER the google map is initialized?

```
function initMap() { 
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
      zoom: 13, 
      center: {lat: 51.501904, lng: -0.115871} 
      }); 

  var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer(); 
  transitLayer.setMap(map); 

}
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work (produces the error `initMap is not a function`)

Comment: That's odd, it works for me on Chrome and Firefox and I am unable to reproduce this error on a different device. Could someone confirm this error?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean saying AFTER the google map is initialized. I suppose you can use one of the events defined for the Map class, for example `tilesloaded` or `idle`.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

So, the code might something like

```
function initMap() { 
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
    zoom: 13, 
    center: {lat: 51.501904, lng: -0.115871} 
  }); 

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function() {
    var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer(); 
    transitLayer.setMap(map);
  });
}
```